# How do I find an element position in std::vector?

Tags: c++, search, stl, vector

I need to find an element position in an std::vector to use it for referencing an element in *another* vector:

```
int find( const vector<type>& where, int searchParameter )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < where.size(); i++ ) {
       if( conditionMet( where[i], searchParameter ) ) {
           return i;
       }
    }
    return -1;
}
// caller:
const int position = find( firstVector, parameter );
if( position != -1 ) {
    doAction( secondVector[position] );
}
```

however `vector::size()` returns `size_t` which corresponds to an `unsigned` integral type that can't directly store `-1`. How do I signal that the element is not found in a vector when using `size_t` instead of `int` as an index?

Comment: I think the title of the question should be changed. The problem is not how to find the element position, it is about referencing elements in two vectors.

Comment: Well if problem is about -1, take a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/), or you can use `return (size_t)-1;`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()` for elements that was not found. It is a valid value, but it is impossible to create container with such max index. If `std::vector` has size equal to `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`, then maximum allowed index will be `(std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()-1)`, since elements counted from 0.

Answer (score 68):

Take a look at the answers provided for this question: [Invalid value for size_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420982/invalid-value-for-sizet). Also you can use std::find_if with std::distance to get the index.

```
std::vector<type>::iterator iter = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), comparisonFunc);
size_t index = std::distance(vec.begin(), iter);
if(index == vec.size()) 
{
    //invalid
}
```

Comment: Or you could check the iterator against `where.end()`, and calculate/use the distance only if not equal. Doesn't affect performance, just keeps the success check immediately after the call to find.

Comment: Beware... this answer mixes signed and unsigned types. `std::distance` returns `ptrdiff_t` which is signed, and this quantity is compared to `vec.size()` returns `size_t` which is unsigned. It is probably okay in this case, but I would try to avoid it in general. The accepted answer avoids this issue.

Answer (score 19):

First of all, do you really need to store indices like this? Have you looked into std::map, enabling you to store key => value pairs?

Secondly, if you used iterators instead, you would be able to return std::vector.end() to indicate an invalid result. To convert an iterator to an index you simply use

```
size_t i = it - myvector.begin();
```

Comment: Getting the difference between iterators gives you a signed type, so you'll get an implicit conversion warning if you then assign it to an unsigned type.

Answer (score 6):

`std::vector` has random-access iterators. You can do pointer arithmetic with them. In particular, this `my_vec.begin() + my_vec.size() == my_vec.end()` always holds. So you could do

```
const vector<type>::const_iterator pos = std::find_if( firstVector.begin()
                                                     , firstVector.end()
                                                     , some_predicate(parameter) );
if( position != firstVector.end() ) {
    const vector<type>::size_type idx = pos-firstVector.begin();
    doAction( secondVector[idx] );
}
```

As an alternative, there's always `std::numeric_limits<vector<type>::size_type>::max()` to be used as an invalid value.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, it is safe to cast away the unsigned portion unless your vector can get REALLY big.

I would pull out the where.size() to a local variable since it won't change during the call.  Something like this:

```
int find( const vector<type>& where, int searchParameter ){
    int size = static_cast<int>(where.size());
    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
       if( conditionMet( where[i], searchParameter ) ) {
           return i;
       }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If a vector has N elements, there are N+1 possible answers for find.  std::find and std::find_if return an iterator to the found element OR end() if no element is found.  To change the code as little as possible, your find function should return the equivalent position:

```
size_t find( const vector<type>& where, int searchParameter )
{
   for( size_t i = 0; i < where.size(); i++ ) {
       if( conditionMet( where[i], searchParameter ) ) {
           return i;
       }
    }
    return where.size();
}
// caller:
const int position = find( firstVector, parameter );
if( position != secondVector.size() ) {
    doAction( secondVector[position] );
}
```

I would still use std::find_if, though.

Comment: +1 for returning `where.size()`. It makes perfect sense to return it. It is consistent with the philosophy of returning `where.end()` if the function were to return iterator instead.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, I think. `find_if_counted.hpp`:

```
#ifndef FIND_IF_COUNTED_HPP
#define FIND_IF_COUNTED_HPP

#include <algorithm>

namespace find_if_counted_impl
{
    template <typename Func>
    struct func_counter
    {
        explicit func_counter(Func& func, unsigned &count) :
        _func(func),
        _count(count)
        {
        }

        template <typename T>
        bool operator()(const T& t)
        {
            ++_count;

            return _func(t);
        }

    private:
        Func& _func;
        unsigned& _count;
    };
}

// generic find_if_counted,
// returns the index of the found element, otherwise returns find_if_not_found
const size_t find_if_not_found = static_cast<size_t>(-1);

template <typename InputIterator, typename Func>
size_t find_if_counted(InputIterator start, InputIterator finish, Func func)
{
    unsigned count = 0;
    find_if_counted_impl::func_counter<Func> f(func, count);

    InputIterator result = find_if(start, finish, f);

    if (result == finish)
    {
        return find_if_not_found;
    }
    else
    {
        return count - 1;
    }
}

#endif
```

Example:

```
#include "find_if_counted.hpp"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<int> container;

int rand_number(void)
{
    return rand()  % 20;
}

bool is_even(int i)
{
    return i % 2 == 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    container vec1(10);
    container vec2(10);

    std::generate(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), rand_number);
    std::generate(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), rand_number);

    unsigned index = find_if_counted(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), is_even);

    if (index == find_if_not_found)
    {
        std::cout << "vec1 has no even numbers." << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "vec1 had an even number at index: " << index <<
            " vec2's corresponding number is: " << vec2[index] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Though I feel like I'm doing something silly... :X Any corrections are welcome, of course.

Comment: The somewhat silly thing is the find_if_counted_impl thing. :) If you don't have a random access iterator, the index is pretty much useless to begin with. If you do have a random access iterator, you can just subtract found_it - begin(). It also seems to me that returning size() as the "not found" value might be more useful, e.g you can be sure that begin() + size() yields an iterator that can be useful for some purposes, whereas begin() + unsigned(-1) never does any good and must always be checked specifically..

Answer (score 1):

You probably should not use your own function here.
Use [find()](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/find.html) from [STL](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html).

Example:

`list L;
L.push_back(3);
L.push_back(1);
L.push_back(7);`

list::iterator result = find(L.begin(), L.end(), 7);
assert(result == L.end() || *result == 7);

Comment: He needs to transfer the iterator to another vector.

Comment: Yeap, that's exactly my problem. Iterator would be okay, but I can't directly use it with another vector.

Answer (score 1):

Take a vector of integer and a key (that we find in vector )....Now we are traversing the vector until found the key value or last index(otherwise).....If we found key then print the position , otherwise print "-1".

```
     #include <bits/stdc++.h>  
     using namespace std;  

     int main()  
      {  
          vector<int>str;  
          int flag,temp key, ,len,num;

           flag=0;
           cin>>len;

           for(int i=1; i<=len; i++)  
           {
               cin>>key;
               v.push_back(key);
           }

           cin>>num;

           for(int i=1; i<=len; i++)  
           {  
             if(str[i]==num)  
             {  
                flag++;  
                temp=i-1;
                break;
             }  
           }

         if(flag!=0)    cout<<temp<<endl;
         else           cout<<"-1"<<endl;   
         str.clear();   

         return 0;  
      }
```

Comment: Take array of integers and a key (that we find in array )....Now we are traversing the array index until found the key value or last index.....If we found key then print the index , otherwise print "-1".

Comment: @rashedcs please edit your answer to include what you've written as a comment!

Comment: @ Marcus Müller please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the notion of vector entirely

```
template< typename IT, typename VT>
int index_of(IT begin, IT end, const VT& val)
{
    int index = 0;
    for (; begin != end; ++begin)
    {
        if (*begin == val) return index;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This will allow you more flexibility and let you use constructs like

```
int squid[] = {5,2,7,4,1,6,3,0};
int sponge[] = {4,2,4,2,4,6,2,6};
int squidlen = sizeof(squid)/sizeof(squid[0]);
int position = index_of(&squid[0], &squid[squidlen], 3);
if (position >= 0) { std::cout << sponge[position] << std::endl; }
```

You could also search any other container sequentially as well.

Comment: Your function will always return 0 (if found) and -1 (when not found).