# How to get position of a certain element in strings vector, to use it as an index in ints vector?

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the index of an element in a vector of `strings`, to use it as an index in another vector of `int` type, is this possible ?

Example:

```
vector <string> Names;
vector <int> Numbers;

 ... 
// condition to check whether the name exists or not
if((find(Names.begin(), Names.end(), old_name_)) != Names.end())  
    {   // if yes
        cout <<"Enter the new name."<< endl;
        cin >> name;
        replace(Names.begin(), Names.end(), old_name_, name);
    }
```

Now I want to get the position of `old_name` in the `Names` vector, to use it in accessing certain element in `Numbers` vector. So that I can say:

```
Numbers[position] = 3 ; // or whatever value assigned here.
```

I tried using:

```
vector <string> :: const_iterator pos;
pos = (find(Names.begin(), Names.end(), old_name_))
Numbers[pos] = 3;
```

but obviously this doesn't work since `pos` is of type string !

Comment: I guess this should http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425349/how-do-i-find-an-element-position-in-stdvector

Comment: You should check out std::map or std::unordered_map.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

To get a position of an element in a vector knowing an iterator pointing to the element, simply subtract `v.begin()` from the iterator:

```
ptrdiff_t pos = find(Names.begin(), Names.end(), old_name_) - Names.begin();
```

Now you need to check `pos` against `Names.size()` to see if it is out of bounds or not:

```
if(pos >= Names.size()) {
    //old_name_ not found
}
```

vector iterators behave in ways similar to array pointers; most of what you know about pointer arithmetic can be applied to vector iterators as well.

Starting with C++11 you can use [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) in place of subtraction for both iterators and pointers:

```
ptrdiff_t pos = distance(Names.begin(), find(Names.begin(), Names.end(), old_name_));
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't see @Bob__ 's comments, maybe deleted? I'm wondering why `ptrdiff_t` is better than `size_t` since `ptrdiff_t ` would raise a warning of comparison between signed and unsigned integer

Comment: @Hiraku He did delete his comment. He suggested using `ptrdiff_t` because it lets you store the distance between any pair of iterators into the same container, even in situations when the result is negative. If we use `size_t` we must be careful not to subtract a larger iterator from a smaller iterator.

Comment: To be more precise, you should add "#include <algorithm>"    (for using std::find). Author of question omitted this "include" too.

Answer (score 111):

If you want an index, you can use `std::find` in combination with [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance).

```
auto it = std::find(Names.begin(), Names.end(), old_name_);
if (it == Names.end())
{
  // name not in vector
} else
{
  auto index = std::distance(Names.begin(), it);
}
```

Comment: why not use const-iterators?

Comment: For beginners: To use `const_iterator`, use cbegin() and cend(). I.e., `auto it = std::find(Names.cbegin(), Names.cend(), old_name_);`, then `auto` would deduce to const_iterator, not a normal iterator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure pointer arithmetic applies the same way here as in arrays.

```
int getVecPos(std::vector<string> vec, string element){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++){
        if(vec[i] == element){
            break;
        }
    }
    if(i == vec.size()){
        std::cout<<"No such element as "<<element<<" found. Please enter again: ";
        std::cin>>element;
        i = getVecPos(vec, element);
    }
        
    return i;
}
```

You can add it to the vec.begin() to get an iterator that you can use for the other vector functions or you can use for finding the index of an element in the array.
Example:-

```
int getVecPos(std::vector<string>, string);//This was the function from earlier.
std::vector<string> UpdateHealables(std::vector<string> healables, string healing_item){
    auto it = healables.begin() + getVecPos(healables, healing_item);
    healables.erase(it);
    return healables;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I am a beginner so here is a beginners answer.
    The if in the for loop gives i which can then be used 
    however needed such as Numbers[i] in another vector.
    Most is fluff for examples sake, the for/if really says it all.

```
int main(){
vector<string>names{"Sara", "Harold", "Frank", "Taylor", "Sasha", "Seymore"};
string req_name;
cout<<"Enter search name: "<<'\n';
cin>>req_name;
    for(int i=0; i<=names.size()-1; ++i) {
        if(names[i]==req_name){
            cout<<"The index number for "<<req_name<<" is "<<i<<'\n';
            return 0;
        }
        else if(names[i]!=req_name && i==names.size()-1) {
            cout<<"That name is not an element in this vector"<<'\n';
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
```