# vector<string>::iterator - how to find position of an element

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, stdvector

I am using the following code to find a string in an `std::vector` of `string` type. But how to return the position of particular element?

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> vec;
    vector<string>::iterator it;

    vec.push_back("H");
    vec.push_back("i");
    vec.push_back("g");
    vec.push_back("h");
    vec.push_back("l");
    vec.push_back("a");
    vec.push_back("n");
    vec.push_back("d");
    vec.push_back("e");
    vec.push_back("r");

    it=find(vec.begin(),vec.end(),"r");
    //it++;

    if(it!=vec.end()){
        cout<<"FOUND AT : "<<*it<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"NOT FOUND"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

`FOUND AT : r`

**Expected Output:**

`FOUND AT : 9`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get position of a certain element in strings vector, to use it as an index in ints vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099707/how-to-get-position-of-a-certain-element-in-strings-vector-to-use-it-as-an-inde)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) for that:

```
auto pos = std::distance(vec.begin(), it);
```

For an `std::vector::iterator`, you can also use arithmetic:

```
auto pos = it - vec.begin();
```

Comment: Thanks! just out of my curiosity what if my vector contains `1000 elements` and using `find` will it be faster or I need to use some sort of `pointer to array`?

Comment: @user2754070 you would have to measure it, but I doubt you'll be faster than `find` in an optimized build.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> vec;
    vector<string>::iterator it;

    vec.push_back("H");
    vec.push_back("i");
    vec.push_back("g");
    vec.push_back("h");
    vec.push_back("l");
    vec.push_back("a");
    vec.push_back("n");
    vec.push_back("d");
    vec.push_back("e");
    vec.push_back("r");

    it=find(vec.begin(),vec.end(),"a");
    //it++;
    int pos = distance(vec.begin(), it);

    if(it!=vec.end()){
        cout<<"FOUND  "<< *it<<"  at position: "<<pos<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"NOT FOUND"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: Some explanation would be helpful

Answer (score 3):

Use following :

```
if(it != vec.end())
   std::cout<< "Found At :" <<  (it-vec.begin())  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this statement:

```
it = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), "r") - vec.begin();
```