# How exactly are data types represented in a computer?

Tags: c, types, kernighan-and-ritchie, kr-c

I'm a beginning programmer reading K&R, and I feel as if the book assumes a lot of previous knowledge. One aspect that confuses me is the actual representation, or should I say existence, of variables in memory. What exactly does a data type specify for a variable? I'm not too sure of how to word this question... but I'll ask a few questions and perhaps someone can come up with a coherent answer for me.

When using getchar(), I was told that it is better to use type "int" than type "char" due to the fact that "int" can hold more values while "char" can hold only 256 values. Since we may need the variable to hold the EOF value, we will need more than 256 or the EOF value will overlap with one of the 256 characters. In my mind, I view this as a bunch of boxes with empty holes. Could someone give me a better representation? Do these "boxes" have index numbers? When EOF overlaps with a value in the 256 available values, can we predict which value it will overlap with?

Also, does this mean that the data type "char" is only fine to use when we are simply assigning a value to a variable manually, such as char c = 'a', when we definitely know that we will only have 256 possible ASCII characters?

Also, what is the actual important difference between "char" and "int"? If we can use "int" type instead of "char" type, why do we decide to use one over the other at certain times? Is it to save "memory" (I use quotes as I do not actually how "memory" exactly works).

Lastly, how exactly is the 256 available values of type char obtained? I read something about modulo 2^n, where n = 8, but why does that work (something to do with binary?). What is the modulo portion of "modulo 2^n" mean (if it has any relevance to modular arithmetic, I can't see the relation...)?

Comment: "when we definitely know that we will only have 256 possible ASCII characters?" nit-pick: There's only 128 characters in ASCII.

Comment: there is more than just "int".. there is unsigned int (0-65535) and signed int (-32767 to 32767)... plain char in most implementations is 0 to 255 in unsigned. You also have short and long. short is two bytes, int is 4 bytes, and long is 8 bytes. See here: http://home.att.net/~jackklein/c/inttypes.html

Comment: Sorry :s Then could I ask why we cannot use the 256 available values of type "char" if we are also using the function getchar() and expecting an EOF at some point?

Comment: You are in for an interesting time. I mean that with no sarcasm, just encouragement. There is a lot of very interesting stuff ahead of you on this road. As Rob has mentioned below, get Petzold's book and read through it. Enjoy learning!

Comment: @withchemicals: because int can also be char and char will rollover back to 0 if it is unsigned (value greater than 255)

Comment: withchemicals: Because "char" doesn't really imply "ASCII". In C, "char" implies "smallest addressable piece of memory", otherwise known as "byte". getchar() simply gives you a byte from a stream (or EOF).

Comment: Many of the answers below assume two's complement representation of numbers.  C makes no such guarantees.  It can run (and does run) on ones' complement machines, and sign-magnitude machines (or any other weird encodings there are!).

Answer (score 11):

Great questions.  K&R was written back in the days when there was a lot less to know about computers, and so programmers knew a lot more about the hardware.  Every programmer *ought* to be familiar with this stuff, but (understandably) many beginning programmers aren't.

At Carnegie Mellon University they developed an entire course to fill in this gap in knowledge, which I was a TA for.  I recommend the textbook for that class: "Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective" http://amzn.com/013034074X/

The answers to your questions are longer than can really be covered here, but I'll give you some brief pointers for your own research.

Basically, computers store all information--whether in memory (RAM) or on disk--in binary, a base-2 number system (as opposed to decimal, which is base 10).  One binary digit is called a bit.  Computers tend to work with memory in 8-bit chunks called bytes.

A char in C is one byte.  An int is typically four bytes (although it can be different on different machines).  So a char can hold only 256 possible values, 2^8.  An int can hold 2^32 different values.

For more, definitely read the book, or read a few Wikipedia pages:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twos_complement

Best of luck!

**UPDATE** with info on modular arithmetic as requested:

First, read up on modular arithmetic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Basically, in a two's complement system, an n-bit number really represents an equivalence class of integers modulo 2^n.

If that seems to make it more complicated instead of less, then the key things to know are simply:

- An unsigned n-bit number holds values from 0 to 2^n-1. The values "wrap around", so e.g., when you add two numbers and get 2^n, you really get zero.  (This is called "overflow".)
- A signed n-bit number holds values from -2^(n-1) to 2^(n-1)-1.  Numbers still wrap around, but the highest number wraps around to the most negative, and it starts counting up towards zero from there.

So, an unsigned byte (8-bit number) can be 0 to 255.  255 + 1 wraps around to 0.  255 + 2 ends up as 1, and so forth.  A signed byte can be -128 to 127.  127 + 1 ends up as -128. (!) 127 + 2 ends up as -127, etc.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain the "modulo" portion of 2^n?

Comment: I would rather have said "back in the days when programming was a lot lower level, closer to the hardware, so learning programming quickly required (and resulted in) a good basic understanding of the underlying hardware".

Comment: Software Monkey: well-said, I think that's more exact than what I wrote.

Comment: withchemicals: Updated answer with some info on modular arithmetic; hope this helps.

Comment: BTW, on some platforms there is at least one character in the C character set whose value exceeds the maximum value for a signed char.  For example, in EBCDIC, '0' is 0xF0.  On such machines, 'char' must be unsigned.  On some other platforms (e.g. some DSP's), sizeof(char)==sizeof(int), and both are able to hold values -32767..32767 (and perhaps other values as well).  On such machines, 'char' must be signed.  Note further that on such machines it would be possible for -1 to be a valid character value, and for EOF to be some value other than -1.

Answer (score 5):

> One aspect that confuses me is the
>   actual representation, or should I say
>   existence, of variables in memory.
>   What exactly does a data type specify
>   for a variable?

At the machine level, the difference between `int` and `char` is only the size, or number of bytes, of the memory allocated for it by the programming language.  In C, IIRC, a `char` is one byte while an `int` is 4 bytes.  If you were to "look" at these inside the machine itself, you would see a sequence of bits for each.  Being able to treat them as `int` or `char` depends on how the language decides to interpret them (this is also why its possible to convert back and forth between the two types).

> When using getchar(), I was told that
>   it is better to use type "int" than
>   type "char" due to the fact that "int"
>   can hold more values while "char" can
>   hold only 256 values.

This is because there are 2^8, or 256 combinations of 8 bits (because a bit can have two possible values), whereas there are 2^32 combinations of 32 bits.  The EOF constant (as defined by C) is a negative value, not falling within the range of 0 and 255.  If you try to assign this negative value to a char (this squeezing its 4 bytes into 1), the higher-order bits will be lost and you will end up with a valid char value that is NOT the same as EOF.  This is why you need to store it into an int and check before casting to a char.

> Also, does this mean that the data
>   type "char" is only fine to use when
>   we are simply assigning a value to a
>   variable manually, such as 0char c =
>   'a', when we definitely know that we
>   will only have 256 possible ASCII
>   characters?

Yes, especially since in that case you are assigning a character literal.

> Also, what is the actual important
>   difference between "char" and "int"?
>   If we can use "int" type instead of
>   "char" type, why do we decide to use
>   one over the other at certain times?

Most importantly, you would pick `int` or `char` at the language level depending on whether you wanted to treat the variable as a number or a letter (to switch, you would need to cast to the other type).  If you wanted an integer value that took up less space, you could use a `short int` (which I believe is 2 bytes), or if you were REALLY concerned with memory usage you could use a `char`, though mostly this is not necessary.

**Edit**: here's a [link](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/C/CONCEPT/data_types.html) describing the different data types in C and modifiers that can be applied to them.  See the table at the end for sizes and value ranges.

Comment: Nitpick: to handle characters you'd stay the hell away from char and use a higher-level abstraction from a library like GLib.

Comment: Sure, but I still think its important to understand what's actually going on at the lower levels.

Comment: In C, an `int` can be 4 bytes, or more, or less.  `int` must be able to represent values between `-32767` and `+32767`.

Comment: int is not necessary 4 bytes. All C says is: short <= int <= long and short >= 2 bytes and long >= 4 bytes. See "The C Programming Language", ANSI C Version, by K&R, page 36.

Comment: Also, in C, `char` may be signed, in which case it *can* store `EOF`, but of course `char` may be unsigned as well, and that's why we use `int` in this case.

Comment: Alok: However, if `char` is signed then it can't store all the valid return values of `getchar` (which are either `unsigned char` values, or `EOF`), so even then you're better off using `int`.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, system memory is one huge series of bits, each of which can be either "on" or "off". The rest is conventions and interpretation.

First of all, there is no way to access individual bits directly; instead they are grouped into bytes, usually in groups of 8 (there are a few exotic systems where this is not the case, but you can ignore that for now), and each byte gets a memory address. So the first byte in memory has address 0, the second has address 1, etc.

A byte of 8 bits has 2^8 possible different values, which can be interpreted as a number between 0 and 255 (unsigned byte), or as a number between -128 and +127 (signed byte), or as an ASCII character. A variable of type `char` per C standard has a size of 1 byte.

But bytes are too small for a lot of things, so other types have been defined that are larger (i.e. they consist of multiple bytes), and CPUs support these different types through special hardware constructs. An `int` is typically 4 bytes nowadays (though the C standard does not specify it and ints can be smaller or bigger on different systems) because 4 bytes are 32 bits, and until recently that was what mainstream CPUs supported as their "word size".

So a variable of type `int` is 4 bytes large. That means when its memory address is e.g. 1000, then it actually covers the bytes at addresses 1000, 1001, 1002, and 1003. In C, it is possible to address those individual bytes as well at the same time, and that is how variables can overlap.

As a sidenote, most systems require larger types to be "word-aligned", i.e. their addresses have to be multiples of the word size, because that makes things easier for the hardware. So it is not possible to have an int variable start at address 999, or address 17 (but 1000 and 16 are OK).

Comment: Again, `int` may be 4 bytes or 2 or even 1, or anything.  It must be able to represent the range +-32767.

Comment: wouldn't it be 2^7 and not 2^8?

Comment: @Alok, yes that's what I say one paragraph higher. @Roboto: Nope. 8 bits means 2^8 different values. One bit has 2 values (2^1), each additional bit doubles this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to completely answer Your question, but I would like to help You understand variables, as I had the same problems understanding them, when I began to program by myself.

For the moment, don't bother with the electronic representation of variables in memory. Think of memory as a continuous block of 1-byte-cells, each storing an bit-pattern (consisting of 0s and 1s).

By solely looking at the memory, You can't determine, what the bits in it represent! They are just arbitrary sequences of 0s and 1s. It is YOU, who specifies, HOW to interpret those bit patterns! Take a look at this example:

```
int a, b, c;
...
c = a + b;
```

You could have written the following as well:

```
float a, b, c;
...
c = a + b;
```

In both cases, the variables a, b and c are stored somewhere in the memory (and You can't tell their type). Now, when the compiler compiles Your code (that is translating Your program into machine instructions), it makes sure, to translate the "+" into integer_add in the first case and float_add in the second case, thus the CPU will interpret the bit patterns correctly and perform, what You desired.

**Variable types are like glasses**, that let the CPU look at a bit patterns from different perspectives.

Answer (score 2):

G'day,

To go deeper, I'd highly recommend Charles Petzold's excellent book "[Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735611319)"

It covers more than what you ask, all of which leads to a better understanding of what's actually happening under the covers.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Really, datatypes are an abstraction that allows your programming language to treat a few bytes at some address as some kind of numeric type. Consider the data type as a lens that lets you see a piece of memory as an int, or a float. In reality, it's all just bits to the computer.

Comment: The OP framed it in terms of hardware, but I agree with you; the individual questions were all better answered with a short introduction to type theory.

Answer (score 1):

- In C, `EOF` is a "small negative number".
- In C, `char` type may be unsigned, meaning that it cannot represent negative values.
- For unsigned types, when you try to assign a negative value to them, they are converted to an unsigned value.  If `MAX` is the maximum value an unsigned type can hold, then assigning `-n` to such a type is equivalent to assigning `MAX - (n % MAX) + 1` to it.  So, to answer your specific question about predicting, "yes you can".  For example, let's say `char` is unsigned, and can hold values `0` to `255` inclusive.  Then assigning `-1` to a char is equivalent to assigning `255 - 1 + 1 = 255` to it.

Given the above, to be able to store `EOF` in `c`, `c` can't be `char` type.  Thus, we use `int`, because it can store "small negative values".  Particularly, in C, `int` is guaranteed to store values in the range `-32767` and `+32767`.  That is why `getchar()` returns `int`.

> Also, does this mean that the data type "char" is only fine to use when we are simply assigning a value to a variable manually, such as char c = 'a', when we definitely know that we will only have 256 possible ASCII characters?

If you are assigning values directly, then the C standard guarantees that expressions like `'a'` will fit in a `char`.  Note that in C, `'a'` is of type `int`, not char, but it's okay to do `char c = 'a'`, because `'a'` is able to fit in a `char` type.

About your question as to what type a variable should hold, the answer is: use whatever type that makes sense.  For example, if you're counting, or looking at string lengths, the numbers can only be greater than or equal to zero.  In such cases, you should use an unsigned type.  `size_t` is such a type.

Note that it is sometimes hard to figure out the type of data, and even the "pros" may make mistakes.  `gzip` format for example, stores the size of the uncompressed data in the last 4 bytes of a file.  This breaks for huge files > 4GB in size, which are fairly common these days.

You should be careful about your terminology.  In C, a `char c = 'a'` assigns an integer value corresponding to `'a'` to `c`, but it need not be ASCII.  It depends upon whatever encoding you happen to use.

About the "modulo" portion, and 256 values of type `char`: if you have `n` binary bits in a data type, each bit can encode 2 values: 0 and 1.  So, you have `2*2*2...*2` (`n` times) available values, or 2<sup>n</sup>.  For *unsigned* types, any overflow is well-defined, it is as if you divided the number by (the maximum possible value+1), and took the remainder.  For example, let's say `unsigned char` can store values `0..255` (256 total values).  Then, assigning `257` to an `unsigned char` will basically divide it by 256, take the remainder (1), and assign that value to the variable.  This relation holds true for unsigned types only though.  See [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863153/why-unsigned-int-0xffffffff-is-equal-to-int-1/1863219#1863219) for more.

Finally, you can use `char` arrays to read data from a file in C, even though you might end up hitting `EOF`, because C provides other ways of detecting `EOF` without having to read it in a variable explicitly, but you will learn about it later when you have read about arrays and pointers (see `fgets()` if you're curious for one example).

Answer (score 0):

According to "stdio.h" getchars() return value is int and EOF is defined as -1.
Depending on the actual encoding all values between 0..255 can occur, there for unsigned char is not enough to represent the -1 and int is used.
Here is a nice table with detailed information http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of K&R is it's conciseness and readability, writers always have to make concessions for their goals; rather than being a 2000 page reference manual it serves as a basic reference and an excellent way to learn the language in general. I recommend Harbinson and Steele "C: A Reference Manual" for an excellent C reference book for details, and the C standard of course.

You need to be willing to google this stuff. Variables are represented in memory at specific locations and are known to the program of which they are a part of within a given scope. A char will typically be stored in 8 bits of memory (on some rare platforms this isn't necessarily true). 2^8 represents 256 distinct posibilities for variables. Different CPU/compilers/etc represent the basic types int, long of varying sizes. I think the C standard might specify minimum sizes for these, but not maximum sizes. I think for double it specifies at least 64 bits, but this doesn't preclude intel from using 80 bits in a floating point unit. Anyway, typical sizes in memory on 32bit intel platforms would be 32 bits (4 bytes) for unsigned/signed int and float, 64 bits (8 bytes) for double, 8 bits for char (signed/unsigned).  You should also look up memory alignment if you are really interested on the topic. You can also at the exact layout in your debugger by getting the address of your variable with the "&" operator and then peeking at that address. Intel platforms may confuse you a little when looking at values in memory so please look up little endian/big endian as well. I am sure stack overflow has some good summaries of this as well.

Answer (score 0):

All of the characters needed in a language are respresented by ASCII and Extended ASCII. So there is no character beyond the Extended ASCII.

While using char, there is probability of getting garbage value as it directly stores the character but using int, there is less probability of it as it stores the ASCII value of the character.

Answer (score 0):

### For your last question about modulo:

> Lastly, how exactly is the 256 available values of type char obtained? I read something about modulo 2^n, where n = 8, but why does that work (something to do with binary?). What is the modulo portion of "modulo 2^n" mean (if it has any relevance to modular arithmetic, I can't see the relation...)?

Think about modulo as a clock, where adding hours eventually results in you starting back at 0. Adding an hour for each step, you go from 00:00 to 01:00 to 02:00 to 03:00 to ... to 23:00 and then add one more hour to get back to 00:00. The "wrap-around" or "roll-over" is called modulo, and in this case is modulo 24.

With modulo, that largest number is never reached; as soon as you "reach" that number, the number wraps around to the beginning (24:00 is really 00:00 in the time example).

As another example, modern humanity's numbering system is Base 10 (i.e., Decimal), where we have digits 0 through 9. We don't have a singular digit that represents value 10. We need two digits to store 10.

Let's say we only have a one-digit adder, where the output can only store a single digit. We can add any two single-digit numbers together, like `1+2`, or `5+4`. `1+2=3`, as expected. `5+4=9`, as expected. But what happens if we add 5+5 or 9+1 or 9+9? To calculate `5+5`, our machine computes `10`, but it can't store the `1` due to its lack of memory capabilities, so the computer treats the `1` as an "overflow digit" and throws it away, only storing the `0` as the result. So, looking at your output for the computation `5+5`, you see the result is `0`, which probably isn't what you were expecting. To calculate `9+9`, your single-digit adding machine would correctly calculate `18`, but, it again, due to hardware memory limitations of storing a maximum of one digit, doesn't have the ability to store the `1`, so it throws it away. The adder CAN however store the `8`, so your result of `9+9` produces `8`.Your single-digit adder is modulo'ing by 10. Notice how you can never reach the number 10 in your output, even when your result **should** be 10 or bigger. The same issue occurs in binary, but with different modulo values.

As an aside, this "overflow" issue is especially bad with multiplication since you need twice the length of your biggest input to multiply two numbers (whether the numbers are binary or decimal or some other standard base) with all the result's digits intact. I.e., if you're multiplying a 32-bit number by another 32-bit number, your result *might* take 64 bits of memory instead of a convenient 32! E.g., 999 (3 digit input) times 999 (3 digit input) =  998,001 (6 digit output). Notice how the output requires double the number of digits of storage compared to one of the inputs' lengths (number of digits).

Back to binary modulo,
A char in the programming language C is defined as the smallest accessible unit (source: I made it up based off what I've been told a hundred times). AFAIK, a single char is always the length of a single Byte. A byte is 8 bits, which is to say, a byte is an ordered group of eight 1s and/or 0s. E.g., 11001010 is a byte. Again, the order matters, meaning that 01 is not the same as 10, much like how 312 is not the same as 321 in Base 10.

Each bit you add gives you twice as many possible states. With **1** bit, you have 2^**1** = 2 possible states (0,1). With **2** bits, you have 2^**2** = 4 states (00,01,10,11), With **3** bits, you have 2^**3** = 8 states (000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111). With 4 bits, you have 2^4 = 16 states, etc. With **8** bits (the length of a Byte, and also the length of a char), you have 2^**8** = 256 possible states.

The largest value you can store in a char is 255 because a char has only 8 bits, meaning you can store all 1s to get the maximum value, which will be 11111111(bin) = 255(dec). As soon as you try to store a larger number, like by adding 1, we get the same overflow issue mentioned in the 1-digit adder example. 255+1 = 256 = 1 0000 0000 (spaces added for readability). 256 takes 9 bits to represent, but only the lower 8 bits can be stored since we're dealing with chars, so the most significant bit (the only 1 in the sequence of bits) gets truncated and we're left with 0000 0000 = 0. We could've added any number to the char, but the resulting char will always be between values 0 (all bits are 0s) and 255 (all bits are 1s).

Since a maximum value of 255 can be stored, we can say that operations that output/result in a char are mod256 (256 can never be reached, but everything below that value can (see the clock example)). Even if we add a million to a char, the final result will be between 0 and 255 (after a lot of truncation happens). Your compiler may give you a warning if you do a basic operation that causes overflow, but don't depend on it.

I said earlier that char can store up to 256 values, 0 through 255 - this is only partially true. You might notice that you get strange numbers when you try to do operations like `char a = 255;`.Printing out the number as an integer (`char a = 128; printf("%d",a);`) should tell you that the result is -128. Did the computer think I added a negative by accident? No. This happened because a char is naturally signed, meaning it's able to be negative. 128 is actually overflow because the range of 0 to 255 is split roughly in half, from -128 to +127. The maximum value being +127, and then adding 1 to reach 128 (which makes it overflow by exactly 1) tells us that the resulting number of `char a = 128;` will be the minimum value a char can store, which is -128. If we had added 2 instead of 1 (like if we tried to do `char a = 129;`), then it would overflow by 2, meaning the resulting char would have stored -127. The maximum value will always wrap around to the minimum value in non-floating point numbers.

- Floating-point numbers still work based on place values (but it's called a mantissa and functions differently) like ints, shorts, chars, and longs, but floating-point numbers also have a dedicated sign bit (which has no additive value) and an exponent.

#### If you choose to look at the raw binary when setting variables equal to literal values like 128 or -5000

For signed non-floating-point numbers, the largest place value get assigned a 1 when the overall number is negative, and that place value gets treated as a negative version of that typical place value. E.g., -5 (Decimal) would be 1xx...x in binary (where each x is a placeholder for either a 0 or 1). As another example, instead of place values being 8,4,2,1 for an unsigned number, they become -8,4,2,1 for a signed number, meaning you now have a "negative 8's place".

**2's Complement to switch between + and - values**: Flip (i.e., "Complement") all bits (i.e., each 1 gets flipped to a 0, and, simultaneously, each 0 gets flipped to a 1)(e.g., -12 = -16 + 4 = 10100 -> 01011). After flipping, add value 1 (place value of 1). (e.g., 01011 + 1 = 01100 = 0+8+4+0+0 = +12). Summary: Flip bits, then add 1.

Examples of using **2's Complement to convert binary numbers into EQUIVALENT signed decimal numbers**:

- 0 = 0
- 1 = -1
- 11 = (-2)+1 = -1
- **111 = (-4)+2+1 = -1**
- 1111 = (-8)+4+2+1 = -1
- 1000 = (-8)+0+0+0 = -8
- **0111 = 0+4+2+1 = 7**
- Notice how 0111 and 111 are treated differently when they're designated as "signed" numbers (instead of "unsigned" (always positive) numbers). **Leading 0s are important.**

If you see the binary number 1111, you might think, "Oh, that's 8+4+2+1 = 15". However, you don't have enough information to assume that. It could be a negative number. If you see "(signed) 1111", then you still don't know the number for certain due to One's Complement existing, but you can assume it means "(signed 2's Complement) 1111", which would be (-8)+4+2+1 = -1. The same sequence of bits, 1111, can be interpreted as either -1 or 15, depending on its signedness. This is why the `unsigned` keyword in `unsigned char` is important. When you write `char`, you are implicitly telling the computer that you want a signed char.

- `unsigned char` - Can store numbers between 0 and 255
- (signed) `char` - Can store number between -128 and +127 (same span, but shifted to allow negatives)