# -2 < 1 = false. Why?

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, unsigned

Hy! Sorry for my bad english, anyway the questions is:

I have this code in objective-c:

```
unsigned int a = 1; 
int b = -2
if (b < a);
```

I expect true and instead the result of the `if(b < a)`is false, why?

Comment: does objective c interpret negative integers as positive? maybe?

Comment: Type unsigned integer type can't hold negative numbers.   Use a debugger to see the actual value in B, you'll see it is not -2

Comment: Guessing that -2 gets cast to unsigned and becomes a very big number.

Comment: Answer with explanation is already here in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084949/arithmetic-operations-on-unsigned-and-signed-integers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C automatically converts -2 into an unsigned int in the comparison. The result is that the comparison is actually (4294967294 < 1), which it is not.

Answer (score 7):

You are comparing signed to unsigned. The signed value is promoted to unsigned, which results in a large number (`0xFFFFFFFD` I think) which is definitely bigger than 1

Answer (score 3):

The int b is promoted to an unsigned temporary variable in order to do the comparison. This means that it ends up being greater than a.

See here for the rules: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t4w2bkb(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Drop the "unsigned".

If you look at the binary representation of -2 and then use that binary value as an unsigned int, then b>a

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare signed and unsigned numbers like that. Most likely the unsigned gets promoted to a signed value resulting in either undefined behaviour or a really big number (depending on how the negative value was stored).