# unsigned and int gotcha

Tags: c, types, type-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Arithmetic operations on unsigned and signed integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084949/arithmetic-operations-on-unsigned-and-signed-integers)

```
unsigned int b=2;
int a=-2;

if(a>b)
    printf("a>b");
else
    printf("b>a");
```

OUTPUT: a>b

```
int b=2;
int a=-2;

if(a>b)
    printf("a>b");
else
    printf("b>a");
```

OUTPUT: b>a

PLEASE, someone explain the output

Comment: A good read for all http://www.a-coding.com/2010/12/beware-usigned-integers.html

Answer (score 1):

In the first case both operands are converted to `unsigned int`, the converted `a` will be `UINT_MAX-1`, which is much *larger* than `b` and hence the output.

Don't compare signed and unsigned integers unless you understand the semantics of arithematic conversions, the results might surprise you.

Comment: What does `-1` get converted to if `-2` maps to `UINT_MAX`?

Answer (score 0):

The following is taken from `The C Programming Language` by `Kernighan` and `Ritchie` - `2.7 Type Conversions` - page 44; the second half of the page explains the same scenario in detail. A small portion is below for your reference.

Conversion rules are complicated when `unsigned` operands are involved. The problem is that comparison between `signed` and `unsigned` values are machine dependent, because they depend on the sizes of the various `integer` types. For example, suppose that `int` is 16 bits long and `long` is 32 bits. Then `-1L < 1U`, because `1U`, which is an `int`, is promoted to a `signed long`. But `-1L > 1UL`, because `-1L` is promoted to `unsigned long` and thus appears to be a larger positive number.

Comment: While true in general, in this case, it is relatively straight-forward; both types are the same size of `int`, albeit one is `signed` and the other `unsigned`.

Answer (score 0):

When signed and unsigned values are compared, and when the unsigned values can't all be represented in the signed type, then the signed operand is promoted to unsigned. This is done with a formula that amounts to a reinterpretation of the 2-s complement bit pattern.

Well, negative numbers have lots of high bits set...

Since your operands are all of the same rank, it's just a matter of unsigned bit patterns being compared.

And so -2 is represented with 111111..110, one less than the largest possible, and it easily beats 2 when interpreted as unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn the operation of the operators in C and the C promotion and conversion rules. They are explained in the C standard. Some excerpts from it plus my comments:

**6.5.8 Relational operators**
**Syntax**
1 relational-expression:
shift-expression
relational-expression < shift-expression
relational-expression > shift-expression
relational-expression <= shift-expression
relational-expression >= shift-expression

**Semantics**
**3 If both of the operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic conversions are
performed.**

**Most operators include this "usual arithmetic conversions" step before the actual operation (addition, multiplication, comparison, etc etc).** *- Alex*

**6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions**

1 Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause conversions and yield result
types in a similar way. The purpose is to determine a common real type for the operands
and result. For the specified operands, each operand is converted, without change of type
domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is the common real type. Unless
explicitly stated otherwise, the common real type is also the corresponding real type of
the result, whose type domain is the type domain of the operands if they are the same,
and complex otherwise. This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions:

- First, if the corresponding real type of either operand is long double, the other
  operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose
  corresponding real type is long double.
- Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is double, the other
  operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose
  corresponding real type is double.
- Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is float, the other
  operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose
  corresponding real type is float.
- Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then the
  following rules are applied to the promoted operands:
- If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.
- Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned
  integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank is
  converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.
- Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
  equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
  signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
  integer type.
- Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent
  all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, then
  the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the
  operand with signed integer type.
- Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
  corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

**6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**

1. When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
2. Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
   until the value is in the range of the new type. (The rules describe arithmetic on the mathematical value, not the value of a given type of expression.)
3. Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
   result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

So, in your `a>b` (with `a` being an `int` and `b` being an `unsigned int`), per the above rules you get `a` converted to `unsigned int` before the comparison. Since `a` is negative (-2), the unsigned value becomes `UINT_MAX+1+a` (this is the `repeatedly adding or
subtracting one more than the maximum value` bit). And `UINT_MAX+1+a` in your case is `UINT_MAX+1-2` = `UINT_MAX-1`, which is a huge positive number compared to the value of `b` (2). And so `a>b` yields "true".

Forget the math you learned at school. Learn how C does it.

Answer (score -2):

In this first case you get the unsigned a converted into a signed int. Then these two are compared.

Type conversion ranks between signed and unsigned types could have the same rank in C99. This is when a unsigned and a signed type have the corresponding types, when this happens the result is up to the compiler.

[Here is a summary of the rules](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules).

Comment: To be blunt but accurate: that is wrong.

Comment: [link](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules) The rank of any unsigned integer type is equal to the rank of the corresponding signed integer type, if any.

Comment: The key (nay, crucial) word 'corresponding' is signally lacking from your answer.  'Convert ions' should probably be 'conversion'.  There is no compiler dependency in the situation asked about in the question; it is completely determined by the C standard.  (And, for the record, I've not down-voted you; at least, not yet.)  You can and should edit your answer to rescue it.  For example, you could add your link to the answer.

Comment: My first try to answer anything here. I hope the changes made it better.

Comment: OK - Welcome to StackOverflow.  FYI: ISO 9089:1999 (C99) §6.3.1.8 'Usual Arithmetic Conversions' includes the statement: _Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
integer type._  That appears to apply to this question, where the unsigned integer is of the same rank as the signed integer, but it also seems to be the opposite of what you've said in your first edit.