# why negative number is taken as true in condition statement?

Tags: c, if-statement, negative-number

Here i am confused with condition statement which has negative number,if in the condition only negative number is given as if(-1) then it is true but if (-1>0) then it become false please explain any one thanks in advance

```
if(-1) // This true why and how?
if(-1>0)//This is false why and how
```

Now what is impact in below code please help to understand

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
  char a[]="he";
  char b[]="she";
  if(strlen(a)-strlen(b)>0)//how it is true ?if(2-3>0)i.e if(-3>0) which is false
    //here why it is true                   
  {
    printf("-ve greater then 0 ");
  }
  else 
  {
    printf(" not greater then 0");
  }
}
```

Comment: The issue with your below code is due to signed/unsigned comparison, not relevant to what you asked above. See: [“strlen(s1) - strlen(s2)” is never less than zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474769/strlens1-strlens2-is-never-less-than-zero)

Comment: Your `strlen()` question is interesting (perhaps the only interesting bit in your question that is not directly answered by any of the numerous documents for learning C). You should have asked only that so that answerers would not focus on the first two trivial questions.

Comment: This is an unsigned integer of type size_t return value of strlen. So will be calculated in unsigned. change to `if((int)strlen(a)-(int)strlen(b)>0)`

Comment: `if(2-3>0)i.e if(-3>0)` -- I don't know how you come to that conclusion. `2-3 > 0` is equivalent to `-1 > 0`.

Comment: What is wrong with `if(strlen(a) > strlen(b))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `if(-1)` // This true why and how?

Any non-zero number is evaluated as `true`.

> `if(-1>0)` //This is false why and how

`-1` is less than `0` that's why expression `-1 > 0` evaluated to `false`.

> `if(strlen(a)-strlen(b)>0)` //how it is true ?if(2-3>0)i.e if(-3>0) which is false
>       //here why it is true

`strlen` returns `size_t` type which is `unsigned`. The result of `strlen(a)-strlen(b` would be an `unsigned int`. But `-1` in not `unsigned`, therefore it is converted to `unsigned` before comparison.`strlen(a)-strlen(b)>0` will result in comparison `UINT_MAX -1 > 0`

Comment: thank u sir but  in above code if(strlen(a)-strlen(b)>0) then this statement should be false coz it is equivalent to if(2-3>0) ie if(-3>0)but why it is true ?

Answer (score 2):

Function `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, which is an unsigned integer type.

For this reason, `strlen(a)-strlen(b)` is an unsigned subtraction. It will produce a nonnegative number because it will produce a `size_t` and all values of `size_t` are nonnegative.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with this answer. Why the down vote ?

Comment: @haccks The downvoter thought that this part of the question shouldn't be answered as it was a duplicate of an existing question. I wonder why a moderator thought it useful to erase the back-and-forth that took place though.

Answer (score 1):

Every value, which is not 0, gets evaluated as true in if sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to existing answer:

```
char a[]="he";
char b[]="she";
if(strlen(a)-strlen(b)>0)
```

strlen returns `size_t`. Result of different of `size_t` would be `size_t` too.
Unsigned numbers are always `>= 0`. In your case it is similar to

```
if((2U - 3U) > 0U)
```

See [live code here](http://ideone.com/NAzsuq).

You should rewrite the condition to:

```
if(strlen(a) > strlen(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea that any nonzero number is considered true is a very old concept in computer science. Think of it as treating the raw bits as inputs to a big OR gate. If any bit is a one, then the output is a one (or true). A negative number is a number where the most significant bit, the sign bit, is a one.