# Comparision between a signed/unsigned value with a negative value

Tags: c, sizeof, unsigned, signed

Program 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    if (sizeof(int) > -1)
        printf("Yes");
    else
        printf("No");
    return 0;
}
```

Output : `No`

Program 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    if (2 > -1)
        printf("Yes");
    else
        printf("No");
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `Yes`

Questions:

1. What is the difference between program 1 and program 2?
2. Why `sizeof(int)` is considered as `unsigned`?
3. Why is `2` in program 2 considered as `signed`?

Comment: `2` is a `signed int` literal. `2u` would be `unsigned`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why sizeof(int) is not greater than -1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466857/why-sizeofint-is-not-greater-than-1)

Comment: [why is -1>strlen(t) true in C?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30295512/995714)

Answer (score 2):

It is common issue with *usual arithmetic conversions* between signed and unsigned integers. The `sizeof` operator returns value of type `size_t`, that is some implementation-defined unsigned integer type, defined in `<stddef.h>` (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19732412/586873)).

Integer constant `-1` is of type `int`. When `size_t` is implemented as "at least" `unsigned int` (which is very likely to happen in your case), then both operands of binary operator `<` are converted to unsigned type. Unsigned value cannot be negative, hence `-1` is conveted into a large number.

Answer (score 1):

The type of the value returned by the `sizeof` operator is `size_t`, which is specified to be an unsigned type (often equivalent to `unsigned long`).

Simple plain integer literals, like `2` or `-1` are *always* of type `int`, and `int` is signed.

If you want an unsigned integer literal, you have to add the `U` suffix, like `2U`.

Comment: "*and int is signed*" -- Isn't it implementation-defined whether an `int` is `signed` or `unsigned`?

Comment: @CoolGuy Yoiu're thinking about `char`, all other integer types are signed.

Comment: @Cool Guy @JoachimPileborg: Or a `int` bit-field.

Comment: Unfamiliar with the term "integer literals".  Integer _decimal_ constants are alway `int, long` or `long long`.  Integer _hexadecimal_ constants are `int, unsigned, long, unsigned long, long long` or `unsigned long long`.  Code can have an `unsigned` constant without a `u` suffix like `0xFFFFFFFF` in a 32-bit world.

Comment: @chux A literal is any constant value embedded directly in the code, so you can have character literals like `'A'`, string literals like `"Foo"`, floating point literals like `12.34` and of course integer literals like `5678`. Some of these literals can be represented in the source code in different formats, for integer literals one can use decimal notation (the default), hexadecimal, octal, and lately binary notation as well.

Comment: Thanks.  The use here of _literal_ vs. _constant_ was not clear to me.  What you call "character literal", the C spec calls "character constant".  Your "floating point literal", the spec calls "floating-point constant".  Your "integer literals" are the C spec's "integer constants",  The only "literals" specified are "string literals" and "compound (string) literals".  These _constants_ and _string-literal_ are 2 forms of a _primary-expression_ amongst other uses.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `sizeof` operator returns a value in `size_t`. This is supposed to be an unsigned type, often implemented as `unsigned int`.

The number `2` by itself is an `int`, not `unsigned int`.