# What causes the overflow of the type conversion of cfloat's INT32_MIN to size_t?

Tags: c++, string, implicit-conversion

Compiling the code, printed below, in Visual Studio 2019 presents the warning:
C26450:... Use a wider type to store the operands.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cfloat>

int main()
{
    size_t b = 4;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (b < INT32_MIN) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

the code above returns:

```
true
```

Substituting b with the literal 4 returns:

```
false
```

INT32_MIN is defined in stdint.h as the literal:
(-2147483647i32 - 1).

What in the '<' operation occurs for this overflow error?
It acts intuitively when b is type cast to int.

Another note, adding the following indicates no overflow error.

```
    std::cout << sizeof(size_t) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(int) << std::endl;
```

Outputs:

```
4
4
```

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t , size_t is unsigned.

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison , the < operator causes conversion to the invoking type on the left hand side.
What occurs in the conversion between this literal (integer type?) and size_t for it to become equal to 2147483648?

Comment: duplicates: [Why is −1 > sizeof(int)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3100365/995714), [why is -1>strlen(t) true?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30295512/995714), [Why does this if condition fail for comparison of negative and positive integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18247919/995714), [Why sizeof(int) is not greater than -1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24466857/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

size_t is an unsigned format. This is due to how data is represented in memory. You would have the same behaviour whit INT32_MIN is exactly 0b10000000000000000000000000000000 which is exactly 2^31 / 2147483648 (unsigned).
if you represent it as a signed 32bit number then it becomes -2^31
you should checkout :
[https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/binary/signed-binary-numbers.html#:~:text=We%20have%20seen%20that%20negative,MSB](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/binary/signed-binary-numbers.html#:%7E:text=We%20have%20seen%20that%20negative,MSB))%20as%20a%20sign%20bit.&text=The%20representation%20of%20a%20signed,then%20the%20number%20is%20negative.