# Applying modulo operation on a value of type int and unsigned integer

Tags: c++, int, unsigned-integer

For example the code below

```
int a = -7777;
int b = 10;
cout<< a % b<<endl;
cout<<(a+b)%b<<endl;
cout<< -7777%10 <<endl;
```

The results are:

```
-7
-7
-7
```

but if I changed the type of b to unsigned int, it has different values;

```
int a = -7777;
unsigned int b = 10;
cout<< a % b<<endl;
cout<<(a+b)%b<<endl;
cout<< -7777%10 <<endl;
```

The resutls are

```
9
9
-7
```

Could any body advise how it is working here? How do the differences come?

Btw: I am using C++ in Xcode latest version.

Comment: And the interesting observation is, neither possibility gives the mathematically correct result 3 (the solution for `b` to `-7777 = 10 * a + b` where `a` is any integer and `0 <= b < 10`). Although of course `-7` is closest because it is equivalent to `3` modulo 10.

Comment: @CompuChip see also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594508/modulo-operator-with-negative-values

Comment: @CompuChip: When it comes to negative numbers, there are two ways to do modulo. One results in -7, and one results in 3.  Both are accurate, and for a long time, some compilers did it one way, and other compilers did it the other way.  C++11 finally standardized one as "correct".

Comment: @CompuChip - 'least non-negative residue' `(0 <= r < |b|)` would have been the superior choice; mathematically, it exhibits a regularity the other conventions don't, and leaves no ambiguity. That doesn't make the other answers 'incorrect' (mod 10) in this case - they're just different conventions.

Answer (score 5):

> cout<< a % b << endl;

In the above line `a` is [converted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084949/arithmetic-operations-on-unsigned-and-signed-integers) to unsigned type (since you declared `b` as `unsigned`) due to *usual arithmetic conversions*.
When I interpreted binary representation of -7777 on my machine as positive value it yields, 4294959519, which might explain the result of 9 in your case.

In this case:

```
cout<< -7777%10 <<endl;
```

no promotion is done since both literals are of type `int` and you see result -7.

Comment: @erip: I think you'll find that it's "implementation defined".