# Loop starting at -1 doesn't print anything

Tags: c, loops, integer, sizeof, negative-number

This program is supposed to print out the elements of `array`, but when it is run, no output is shown.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS  (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))

int array[] = { 23, 34, 12, 17, 204, 99, 16 };

int main() {
    int d;
    for (d = -1; d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 2); d++) 
        printf("%d\n", array[d + 1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't this program show any output?

Comment: A macro with a hardcoded variable name is asking for trouble.

Comment: Changing `d=0` does output things though

Comment: @TonyTannous but it doesn't explain what is the problem in the OP

Comment: @CIsForCookies it is the comment section. I didn't tell him to change `d=0` or provide a solution. I was just wondering.

Comment: You should ask your compiler. It often will tell you what the problem is. Also in this case. For *gcc* and *clang* use `-Wall -Wextra`, for Visual C(++) at least `/W3`, preferably `/W4` at least when troubleshooting a problem.

Comment: Just in passing, you don't need the parentheses around `TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 2`.

Comment: @jackarms: Normally I'd agree with you but the variable is global. This code is equivalent to #define TOTAL_ELEMENTS 7 int array [7] = {...}; but easier to maintain.

Comment: @Joshua There are plenty of other problems that are a lot bigger; might as well call out bad code when you see it, to discourage people from copying it.

Comment: Can users please settle on one canonical title and leave overly specific details out of it? Also, for users voting to close as off-topic - it is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: This question has been [answered a huge number of times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=define+TOTAL_ELEMENTS+sizeof%28array%29). I have added a number of dups and they all answer this sufficiently.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ At least 3 links above has got correct, quality answers and at least one of them quotes the C standard. That's good enough IMO. Obviously you are claiming yours is the *best* among them.You are free to re-open it if you disagree.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

`sizeof` returns an unsigned integer, so `TOTAL_ELEMENTS` is also unsigned.

`d` is signed. Initially, `d` is `-1`. However, when doing the comparison, `d` is implicitly typecast to unsigned, so it is no longer `-1` when being compared to `TOTAL_ELEMENTS`, it is actually `UINT_MAX` (which is `4294967295` on my machine, but might differ for others).

Also,

If you want to fix this, typecast `TOTAL_ELEMENTS` to `int`:

```
for(d = -1; d <= (int)(TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 2); d++)
```

This will print:

```
23
34
12
17
204
99
16
```

As you'd expect. You may also want to look at [Comparison operation on unsigned and signed integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084949/comparison-operation-on-unsigned-and-signed-integers) for more information on the topic of signed-unsigned comparisons.

It is worth noting that turning on compiler warnings would've helped you figure out what was going on (as observed by hyde in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45657517/why-isnt-this-c-program-printing-anything/45657570#comment78273237_45657517)):

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra test.c
test.c:7:17: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-compare]
      for(d = 0; d < TOTAL_ELEMENTS; d++) 
              ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

---

Alternatively, why not start `d` at `0` and run to `TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 1` instead? You can even drop the typecast, that is necessary only for the corner case of `d = -1`.

```
for(d = 0; d < TOTAL_ELEMENTS; d++) 
    printf("%d\n", array[d]);
```

---

As a footnote, here are the relevant C99 Standard excerpts:

1. **6.3.1.8p2** defines the conversion from signed to unsigned type.

   > If the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then
   >   the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the
   >   operand with unsigned integer type.
2. **6.3.1.3p2** defines how the conversion is done: By adding `UINT_MAX + 1` to the signed representation.

   > If the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value
   >   that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the
   >   range of the new type.

   So `-1` => `-1 + (UINT_MAX + 1)` = `UINT_MAX`, for this scenario.

Answer (score 38):

My gcc outputs this warning:

```
warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-compare]
      for(d = 0; d < TOTAL_ELEMENTS; d++)
```

which means that `(TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2)` is `unsigned int` while `d` is `signed int`. This makes the expression always `false` for the initial value of `d`, since `(unsigned int)(-1) > (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2)`.

Comment: yeah. The lesson: always enable all warnings and read them

Comment: The expression is not *always false*, it is false for the initial value of `d`.

Answer (score 4):

Binary operations between different integral types are performed within a "common" type defined by so called usual arithmetic conversions. So int d is of singed type initialized with value -1. Which when convert into unsigned int it will return maximum of unsigned int which is much much greater than the value returned by 
TOTAL_ELEMENTS.

Comment: `unsigned int` in your answer should be `size_t`. Other than that, you are on point.