# What are the hazards of comparing expression of different signedness in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, warnings, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

I'm use to use gcc and g++ with -Wall and -Wextra flags since I don't want my code to contain any warnings. Sometimes I understand the reason why I should solve the warnings that comes up after compiling but some other times I don't. One example is the following warning:

```
warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘unsigned int’ [-Wsign-compare]
```

To solve this warning I check the consistency of the `int` (or `unsigned int`, it depends on the cases) and the convert one type to the other. My question is: what are the possible hazard of not perform this checks?

Comment: The rules (simplifying somewhat) say that the signed value is converted to unsigned before the comparison happens. This leads to counter intuitive results, for example signed `-1` will be greater than unsigned `0`. In other words the behaviour is well defined, it's just not what most people expect.

Comment: One possible hazard is various kinds of bugs. The number of possible bugs in C++, due to these kinds of errors, are unlimited.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparison operation on unsigned and signed integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084949/comparison-operation-on-unsigned-and-signed-integers)

Answer (score 0):

Integers and unsigned integers have the same amount of bits. However, for the signed integer, because of the way one's complement (and with c++20 two's complement) works, the first bit can be interpreted as a “sign bit“: When it is 1, the number is negative.

So an unsigned int with a 1 as first bit is a very large number, whereas a signed int with a 1 as first bit is a negative number. Comparing the two numbers will thus not work, which is why you have to provide an explicit conversion.

Comment: 2's complement is mandatory only recently, 1's complement was also possible (even if same result).

Comment: @Jarod42 edited accordingly

Comment: Anyway, internal representation is not the important part, but the promotion/conversion/casting between both.

Comment: The question was about "potential hazards", not the casting.