# K&R chapter 2: Difference between u and l integer suffix in C

Tags: c

I am a student, going through the book by Kerningham and Ritchie for C.

A line in the book says that `-1l` is less than `1u` because in that case `unsigned int` is promoted to signed `long`. But `-1l > 1ul` because in this case `-1l` is promoted to unsigned `long`.

I can't really understand the promotion properly. What will be the value of `-1l` when it is promoted to unsigned long? It'll be great if anyone can help.
Thanks.

Comment: Don't you mean: "But -1l > 1ul because in this case -1l is promoted to **`unsigned`** `long`.

Comment: Hey, don't fall for the "answer with the highest votes and at the top must be best and I'll just accept that one"... Decide for yourself, nd give credit to the person that put the most time and clarity in his/her answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're learning C, if you have a question, just write yourself a simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
  int si = -1;
  unsigned int ui = 1;
  if ( si > ui ) printf("-1l > 1u\n");
  else           printf("-1l <= 1u\n");
}
```

You'll see that `-1l > 1u` is shown for the output.

Because both `si` and `ui` have the same rank (they're both `int`s), the rule says that the negative value will be promoted to unsigned at set to `UINT_MAX` which is the largest possible unsigned value.

Comment: -1: This is a great way to discover implementation defined behavior and label that as standard. Although your answer is correct, I feel that trial and error "Just Doesn't Cut It" when there's implementation defined behavior...

Comment: @rubenvb - `gcc -std=c99 test.c`.  So when your program doesn't work, you include a note that says it would work if only your compiler wasn't messed up?  I think this kind of rudimentary question can be safely answered by testing.

Comment: You'd be surprised at what is undefined when you test anything you throw at it. Stuff like `sizeof` will differ immensely from platform to platform, to give only a simple example. And all the differences are perfectly legal. And undefined behavior != "program doesn't work". It may work, it may not, it may eat your children, it may give you a high five.

Comment: no, the result will differ depending on the size of integer types.

Comment: @ninjalj: I agree, that's why I said "same rank" (quoting from my reference).  Saying "same size" would probably have been clearer.

Answer (score 2):

In `-1l > 1ul` the `-1l` is promoted to `unsigned long`, and by definition and Standard, -1 cast to an `unsigned` type will be the largets value representable by that `unsigned` type.

I got my inspiration from memory of [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863153/why-unsigned-int-0xffffffff-is-equal-to-int-1/1863219#1863219) to a quite relevant question.

And after looking at the C99 draft I have lingering around, see for example 6.3.1.3(2), where it says the maximum value representable by the type will be added or subtracted from the original value until it fits in the new type. I must warn you that `char`, although it is an integer type, is treated special: it is implementation defined if `char` is signed or unsigned. But that is, strictly, beside the question at hand.

Comment: +1 for link to additional answer pointing out representation independence.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit promotions are one of the most difficult things in the C language. If you have a C code expression looking like

if(-1l > 1ul)

then no "integer promotions" take place. Both types are of the same size, but different signedness. -1l will then be converted to unsigned long with a very large value. This is one of the rules in the "usual arithmetic conversions".

Comment: Those are the official terms used by the standard.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a conversion. Promotions go from types with less rank than an integer to integer.

The rules for integer conversions in C are somewhat complex. They are, as per ISO C99 §6.3.1.8 ¶1:

> Otherwise, the integer promotions are
>   performed on both operands. Then the
>   following rules are applied to the
>   promoted operands:
>
> If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is
>   needed.
>
> Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have
>   unsigned
>         integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion
>   rank is
>         converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.
>
> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
>   greater or
>         equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand
>   with
>         signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with
>   unsigned
>         integer type.
>
> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can
>   represent
>         all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer
>   type, then
>         the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type
>   of the
>         operand with signed integer type.
>
> Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
>         corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

I'll try to explain them:

Try to convert to the larger type. When there is conflict between `signed` and `unsigned`, if the larger (including the case where the two types have the same rank) type is `unsigned`, go with `unsigned`. Otherwise, go with `signed` only in the case it can represent all the values of both types.

Comment: What you cite is the usual arithmetic conversions. The integer promotions are the conversion that takes place of smaller types like char and short, whenever they appear in any expression. The integer promotions are found at 6.3.1.1.

Comment: Fair enough, though to be picky there's also other promotions, like the oddity called "the default argument promotions".