# How do I check whether an unsigned int variable contains a negative number?

Tags: c, unsigned-integer

I have the following code:

```
int main()
{ 
    int i;
    unsigned int j;

    printf("Type a number:  ");
    scanf("%d", &i);

    j = i;

    if (________)
    {
        printf("Negative!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What would I put in the if statement in order to check whether the unsigned variable "j" contains a negative number?

Comment: By definition, an `unsigned int` does not contain negative numbers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9045436/3779597

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169692/assigning-negative-numbers-to-an-unsigned-int

Comment: Check for an equivalent negative `int` value only requires checking the highest bit, if it is `1`, then that unsigned number would be represented as a negative `int` value -- but you would have to further check that the value does not exceed `INT_MIN` before proceeding with any such conversion, otherwise you need to extend to a long value.

Comment: Your answer is `if (i >> 31 & 1) printf ("value is negative\n");`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: That makes some assumptions about how integers are represented. Those assumptions are *nearly* 100% valid, but they're unnecessary. Just test the value of `i`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do simply this:

```
  if((int)j < 0) 
  {
   printf("Negative!\n");
  }
```

Comment: That's likely, but not guaranteed, to work. Converting a value greater than `INT_MAX` to `int` yields an implementation-defined result.

Answer (score 2):

You could just check the variable `i` as for example

```
if ( i < 0 )
{
    //...
}
```

or you could write for example

```
if ( j > INT_MAX )
{
    //...
}
```

because the internal representation of non-negative values of type `int` coincides with the internal representation of the same values of type `unsigned int`. At least it will work for the 2 complement representation of integer numbers.

And at last you could check the sign bit.

Comment: Note that the sign bit can be set if the value is negative zero (for sign-magnitude systems).

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it :

```
#include<stdio.h>
/* This is in easier to verify example.
 * I have used char to represent integers that fits in one byte.
 * char is one byte in my system
 * In case of an overflow, the numbers are wrapped around.
 * You could check with bigger types as you please.
 */

int main(void)
{
unsigned char x;
char y;
        printf("Size of char is %zd\n",sizeof(char));
        printf("Enter an integer : ");
        scanf("%d",&x);
        y=x;
        printf("Number is %s when converted to signed\n",\
                             (y>=0?"positive":"negative"));
return 0;
}
```

Checking the same with `INT_MIN` or `INT_MAX` requires you to include `limits.h` header file. Bit manipulation as pointed
out by David is yet another option.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i;
unsigned int j;

// store a value in i

j = i;
```

To test whether `j` contains a negative number:

```
if (0)
{
    printf("Negative!\n");
}
```

An unsigned integer can *never* hold a negative value.

If the value of `i` is negative, then it will be converted to some positive value when you assign it to `j`. If you want to know whether the value of `i` is negative, you should test `i`, not `j`.

```
if (i < 0) {
    puts("i is negative");
}
else {
    puts("i is not negative");
}
puts("j is not negative");
```

Note that converting the value of `j` back to `int` is not reliable. Conversion of a value exceeding `INT_MAX` to type `int` yields an implementation-defined result (or raises an implementation-defined signal). It's very likely you'll get back the original value of `i`, but why bother? If you want to test the value of `i`, test the value of `i`.