# why would the foreign keys giving me an error when the data types match

Tags: mysql

So I am trying to create these tables where the mechanics table would be able to pull the information when I use the JOIN SQL statement in terms of the carid.

Cars table

| carid | VIN | Make | YEAR | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Mechanics table

| mechanicid | firstname | lastname | title | carid | currentcar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

```
CREATE TABLE cars(
carid INT (100) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
VIN INT (255) NOT NULL,
Make VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
Year Year(4) NOT NULL,
Color VARCHAR(10)
);
Create Table mechanic(
mechanicid INT (100) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
firstname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
carid INT (100) NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(carid) REFERENCES cars(carid)
);
```

But I get this error

Error Code: 3780. Referencing column 'carid' and referenced column 'carid' in foreign key constraint 'mechanic_ibfk_1' are incompatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INT UNSIGNED is not the same type as INT.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=b7524e0710227255fd1b0cc01f4f1b49)

Note that display widths for integer types don't really do anything and are now deprecated.  And `INT (255)` doesn't make much sense anyway.

Comment: Adding on to this.  For more info see:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045436/the-real-difference-between-int-and-unsigned-int