# Runtime error dividing by -1

Tags: c++, xcode, integer-division, secure-coding

I don't doubt the need to check for division by zero. I've never heard of checking for division by negative one though!

```
if( *y == 0 )
    return 0; //undefined
else
    return *x / *y;
```

`x, y` are pointers to `int32_t`, I include this detail in case of relevance.

At runtime, if `*x==0x80000000, *y==0xffffffff`, I get the error (in Xcode):

> EXC_ARITHMETIC (code=EXC_I386_DIV, subcode=0x0)

All I can find online is suggestions that it is division by zero, but as you can see from the check above, and I can see from the debug window, that is not the case here.

What does the error mean, and how can I fix it?

Comment: If `y==0xffffffff`, then it's not likely a valid pointer to a int32_t as you claim.

Comment: @Paul Thanks - typo, I meant `*y`

Comment: See [why unsigned int 0xffffffff is equal to int -1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863153/why-unsigned-int-0xffffffff-is-equal-to-int-1) for a discussion about number representation and how on different machine architectures there are some numbers such as zero and negative one whose representation can vary.

Comment: Are the values that you give really for `x` and `y`,  or rather for `*x` and `*y` ?  No other thread that could change the value of `*y` between the `if` and the `return` statement ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

2's complement representation is asymmetric: there is one more negative number than positive number, and that negative number has no positive counterpart. Consequently, negating `MIN_INT` is an integer overflow (where `MIN_INT` is the value whose only 1-bit is the sign bit, 0x80000000 for 32-bit integers).

`MIN_INT / -1` is, therefore, also an arithmetic overflow. Unlike overflow from subtraction (which is rarely checked), overflow when dividing can cause a trap, and apparently that's what is happening in your case.

And, yes, technically speaking you should check for the `MIN_INT / -1` overflow case before dividing, because the result is undefined.

**Note:** In the common case of Intel x64 architecture, division overflow does trap, exactly the same as division by 0. Confusingly, the corresponding Posix signal is `SIGFPE` which is normally thought of as "Floating Point Exception", although there is no floating point in sight. The current Posix standard actually glosses `SIGFPE` as meaning "Erroneous Arithmetic Operation".

Comment: Is there a 'best practice' for what to do instead? e.g., decide the result is zero, or `INT_MAX`, or something else?